# How to catch and override every XHR request inclusive Native requests

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Traditional  solutions catch only xhr in user js.
I tried Xhr.prototype override , it doesnt effect native xhr request.

I want to catch every all xhr request(all fetch api request) [Every request that seen in chrome devtool network tab]  after dom loaded.

More example: 
`<video src="aaa.mp4">` //browser native request for video and we see in the devtool 
Though I set the window.XMLHttpRequest = undefined   , browser can request .  But I cannot xhr request due to undefined.

If I override XHR  , I can generate custom response  without ask to server.

Comment: *"it doesnt effect native xhr request"* What's a "native xhr request"? *"More example:  <video src="aaa.mp4"> //browser native request for video"* That's native, yes, but not XHR -- hence XHR interception techniques don't work.

Comment: I found some things  , I guess it possible in ServiceWorker wrapping the requests.

Comment: Yes, absolutely -- I ***really*** should have mentioned that in my answer. You might want to un-accept my answer and post your own about using a service worker. Or would you prefer I edit my answer? (I've gone ahead and updated my answer [and turned it into a CW] so it's not actually wrong anymore, but just let me know if you post your own and un-accept mine, and I'll delete it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser's own network requests aren't made through XHR at all.

If your goal is to intercept all of the browser's network requests for the page, you'd need to use a *service worker* to do that ([spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API)).